# Why can't I refer to a class or struct created in same directory in a Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift

In my limited experience with Xcode, I can not figure out why a newly composed class or struct can not be referred to existing class file like below.

[image]

Do I need to import Card in advance to use it?

Comment: This should work. Are both _Concentration.swift_ and _Card.swift_ in the list of "Compile Sources" of the _Concentrator_ target?

Comment: No need to import Card,Clean the project and rebuild should be able to find it without any hassle if that doesn't work go to Xcode->preferences->DerivedData delete derived data folder, clean and rebuild that should be enough

Comment: Works fine for me. I only tried because it looked like your syntax is correct. I *do* see some odd things though - missing spaces before the opening bracket in `Concentration` and before/after the equal sign in `isFacedUp`. Also, something I've faced at times is the need to (a) build your project with the `Card` declaration *before* adding code that uses it.

Comment: Select "Card"and make sure that it is added to the app target.

Comment: After cleaning project and deleting files in DerivedData directory, the error still exists. I restart Xcode and the 'Card' can be resolved as a type. I'm not sure how this happened and not quite sure whether restart or clean made it work

Comment: Ah. Didn't think of this in my last comment. I've had this happen before - a "ghost" error. Xcode reports an error... maybe legit... and after correcting things, everything actually *builds* fine and there's a display of no errors, but the previous error is still there in the editor. Clean doesn't help, but shutting down and restarting Xcode does, probably because it automatically tries to build the newly reopened project. I chalk it up to a bug - er, behavior of Xcode 9 and/or Swift 4. I know they made a large amount of editor "improvements" and have believed this to be a side effect.

Comment: @dfd it seems restart is a remedy for every ghost error. LOL

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer should be the comment from @dennis-vennink above.

To others that might not read the comment, the file must be marked to be part of the Target for the application otherwise it will be marked as unknown by the compiler.

To fix in Xcode, click the file and look at the Target Membership section in the File Inspector and ensure that your application Target is selected.